# Read a binary stream file from a socket and save it to a database in java

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

i read the socket that have a binaryfile transmitted, like:

```
DataInputStream input= null;
input = new DataInputStream(socket11.getInputStream());
String inpstring= input.readUTF();
```

And get the data field like this:

```
byte[] datast= inpstring.substring(s, e).getBytes();
```

the 's' and the 'e' are index of the start and end in input string

how can I use the above byte array in an SQL INSERT statement?

Answer (score 0):

Stop right there. `readUTF()/writeUTF()` are for reading/writing UTF character strings of up to 64k in length. Not for binary. And `readUTF()` can only read data that was written by `writeUTF().` You're using the wrong API for the wrong purpose. `String` is not a container for binary data. You should be using the plain `read()` and `write()` methods, or possibly `readFully().` Note that `write()` has an overload where you can specify an offset and length.

You need to read as above and write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and get the byte array from that, or write direct to a BLOB.